# React - How to modify the html inside root?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript

Maybe its a stupid question but:

I have an external Typescript-React app implemented into my code, but in order to add some CSS into one particular DIV (which doesnt have .class or #id) i need to reach the HTML code thats its inside root, how can i reach this HTML code?

Obviously i am able to see the code via Dev-tools but these changes doesn’t get saved after refreshing the page, and also I don’t think that modifying the web page via dev-tools could be considered as a good practice…

I tried to find the HTML file but its not inside my files or neither inside node_modules,

Thank you in advance,

Best Regards.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

React HTML is all in JavaScript. In the node_modules, look for index.js and see if you can find the className or id attribute.

Alternatively, you can go to the github repo of the component and browse the code files.